# 68K Motorola Assembly Simulator

Tags: installed-programs

I use the 68020 IDE Motorola assembly on my windows 7. It's a program that compiles and run my assembly code (along with other languages). When I run my program, it shows every step of the execution or if there are any errors in my codes. I just switched to Ubuntu 17. and I need a replacement for that program. I know I can learn to install Wine but I want to see if there exists a simulator that works like the one I use.

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question and give some more details?

Comment: OP wants basically a simulator of Motorola 68000 processor, which were very popular in the past. I've seen something in the Ubuntu repositories on it a while back, so there's definitely something OP wants

Comment: The question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Hatari has a debugger with single stepping https://hatari.tuxfamily.org/doc/debugger.html, see `apt list hatari`.